# Integration with the Dirac delta function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, notation, integration, dirac-delta-distributions

I have equation like

$$I = \int \prod\limits_{i=1}^{N} dr_{i}e^{-\mathrm i\beta \int dr \sum\limits_{i}q_{i}\delta(r-r_{i})\phi(r)}.$$

First, I did integration in the exponent and got

\begin{align}
I & = \int \prod\limits_{i=1}^{N}dr_{i}e^{-\mathrm i \beta q \sum\limits_{i} \phi(r_{i})} = \int \prod\limits_{i=1}^{N}dr_{i}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{N}e^{-\mathrm i \beta q \phi(r_{i})} = \prod\limits_{i=1}^{N} \int dr_{i} e^{-\mathrm i \beta q \phi(r_{i})} \\ & = \left(\int dr_{i} e^{-\mathrm i \beta q \phi(r_{i})}\right)^{N}.
\end{align}

But, in the reference, the result of $I$ is

$$I = \left(\int dr e^{-\mathrm i \beta q \phi(r)}\right)^{N}.$$

The difference between my calculation and reference is index $i$ in the result. Can we discuss this situation?

Comment: the integration variable is dummy, so the presence of the index "i" is superfluous. You can also call it with another name, say "dz" instead of "dr".

Comment: @kludg  in this case you can factorize everything, the calculation outlined is correct. The only "problem" is notational (i.e. realizing that the integration variable is dummy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integration variables can be renamed at will:
$$
\int dr_{i} e^{-\mathrm i \beta q \phi(r_{i})}
=
\int dr e^{-\mathrm i \beta q \phi(r)}
.
$$